# Any Coinbase API to QueryUserBalance with Mail

Tags: coinbase-api

I want to Query the Balance of a User Using a Http Request and Mail Is it Possible? I need it for my Discord Bot

Comment: Your question should be a bit more concise. "i am using this endpoint, here is a code sample i'm using, here is my error/invalid response. how do I do X"

Answer (score 0):

Utilise a combination of Coinbase API endpoints, accumulate all wallets and convert crypto units to currency.

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference

Comment: Dm me on Telegram @Z6LUL